# What do we meant by "Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.common.collect_ [Sanitized]" in liferay 7.2

Tags: maven, liferay, build-dependencies

I am creating a hook in liferay 7.2 but unfortunately when I deploy it.I come across this error. I had tried increasing version of "com.google.collections" dependency and  also tried adding guauva
a dependency but nothing seems to resolve this error.

My dependencies in Pom.xml is as such:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-collections</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
                    <artifactId>biz.aQute.bndlib</artifactId>
                    <version>4.3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.liferay</groupId>
                    <artifactId>com.liferay.ant.bnd</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.6</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
```

```
Error :
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.allen.portal.hook [1272]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.google.common.collect_ [Sanitized]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1106)
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1139)
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher._process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1001)
    at com.liferay.portal.file.install.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:313)
```

If you have any ways to resolve this error, please help me out

Comment: com.google.collections is really a need? Because liferay osgi context is missing this bundle and your project is missing.
Instead of solve that, maybe consider yourself if it's necessary

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated: You're using an rc2 version released in October 2009, when a release was made in December 2009? Seriously?

It looks like you're building an OSGi module, which compiles fine (because you provide the dependency). However, that does not mean that the google collections code ends up in your jar as well. The runtime expects to find it though - and as Google collections is not an OSGi bundle itself, you'll have several choices:

- repackage it as OSGi bundle (and deploy it to the runtime) (or [find someone who did it already](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.bundles/google-collections?repo=atlassian-public))
- repackage it within your own bundle
- use a different implementation. Chances are that collections utility code from 2009 has found its way into more current implementations and is no longer necessary.

In short: In one way or another, you'll need to make your dependencies available at runtime. Either by fattening your own bundle (but be careful: You can't pass those collections around to other bundles if they bring their own implementation) or by relying on the implementation being available to the runtime.

The third alternative is to switch to an implementation where it's easier to make it available at runtime, preferably as OSGi bundle.

Comment: How to repackage it as OSGi bundle, I am sorry I am really new into this.

Comment: see my edit. But first and foremost, assume you don't need 11 years old rc2 code...

Comment: Well, the reason I had used google.collection is bcause I have used 'Lists' in my code and I had tried to use the more latest version of google.collection like 1.0 but still it didn't work.Also I tried repackaging, it also didn't work.

Comment: You don't need to repackage. Just use the Atlassian one that I've linked: They have repackaged as OSGi bundle already. You'll need the compile time dependency _and_ deploy it to the runtime environment. Or, rewrite your code to use a different (and/or newer) library/implementation. It's not like the problem of collections hasn't been solved a couple of times since 2010.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in so detail, but when i tried to use Atlassian dependency.  I am getting error " Could not find artifact com.atlassian.bundles:google-collections:jar:1.0 in central".Any suggestion how to move forward.

Comment: is there an equivalent for Gradle's compileInclude? that might help.